# How can I avoid roundoff error when calculating the difference $\textrm{erfc}(a) - \textrm{erfc}(b)$?

Tags: numerical-analysis, computer-arithmetic

[In this excellent answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/20913/9466), it is recommended that one make use of the $\textrm{erfcx}$ function to avoid roundoff error in calculating  dealing with $x < 25$ (approximately). So, one scales their answer by $e^{x^2}$, and then scales back, I suppose (?) to recover the number they are really looking for?

What if we have the case where we need to calculate $\textrm{erfc}(a) - \textrm{erfc}(b)$? I could write:

$$\textrm{erfcx}(a) - \textrm{erfcx}(b) = e^{a^2}\textrm{erfc}(a) - e^{b^2}\textrm{erfc}(b) $$

but that's not particularly helpful if I want to numerically integrate the function ($x, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$):

$$ \int_{a}^{b} e^{x^2}(\textrm{erf}(x) - \textrm{erf(a)})\;\textrm{d}x = \int_{a}^{b} e^{x^2}(\textrm{erfc}(a) - \textrm{erfc(x)})\;\textrm{d}x$$

If $a$ and $b$ are close enough/large enough in magnitude (not large in terms of sign) then we get catastrophic cancellation. For example, try $a = -16.85$ and $b = -16.08$. Rescaling inside the integrand would seem to be unhelpful, rather than helpful!

What do?

If you have Python, [here's the toy problem script on Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/bmer/eed97c79e8ba2d793e0d). It implements many of the recommendations provided in this answer to avoid overflow errors, but still runs into underflow problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do.  I am assuming you want to evaluate the integral using some sort of quadrature.  This will work for that.

Note that we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{x=a}^b \exp(x^2) (\mathrm{erf}(x) - \mathrm{erf}(a))\,\mathrm{d} x 
&=
\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{x=a}^b \exp(x^2) \int_{\tau = a}^x \exp(-\tau^2) \, \mathrm{d} \tau\, \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{x=a}^b \int_{\tau= a}^x \exp(x^2-\tau^2) \mathrm{d} \tau\, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
$$

And in the triangle of integration, the integrand is strictly positive so you shouldn't have any cancellation.

Comment: I tried this out, and in my excitement thought that it worked, but it doesn't seem to. Even with this method, I simply get an integral result of "zero", which makes me think things were so small during the process, that they got rounded off to zero? here's the wolfram link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Be%5E%28x%5E2%29*e%5E%28-y%5E2%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+-16.85%2C+-16.08%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-16.85%2C+x%7D%5D

Comment: fred, [here's the link fixed up](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Be%5E%28x%5E2+-+y%5E2%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+-16.85%2C+-16.08%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-16.85%2C+x%7D%5D); I also tried this out in Matlab, and Matlab gives a small number (on the order of `1e-7`), so perhaps Matlab doesn't suffer from Wolfram Alpha's issues?

Comment: I think it was a Wolfram issue. Matlab works fine.

Comment: I am a little nervous about this.  I had assumed that $a$ and $b$ were both positive.  Can you explain what you need this for?  You probably need to have some sanity checks before you take Matlab's answer as the gospel truth.  I gave the integral to Mathematica and it said it was 0.0293917959...

Comment: That's what Matlab gave it as too! Wolfram Alpha can't handle it though. I am not sure if I can really explain what I need this for, because it may take more space than the comments provide ("I am calculating the mean time it takes for something to happen, given a force"). $a$ and $b$ are not necessarily positive, but they are necessarily negative -- they depend on "force". So, basically I have a mean time given force function, and for various values of the force, I can plot out the mean time. The derivative of this function then tells me how the mean time changes as the force changes.

Comment: This derivative matches the behaviour provided by doing this integration (for various values of $a$ and $b$, i.e. various values of force). So, that's a sanity check?

Comment: I just realized what might have made you think that $a$ and $b$ are necessarily positive: when I said that they are "large enough", I mean, "large enough in magnitude"; I will correct this in the OP.

Comment: What Mathematica input did you use by the way? `NIntegrate[e^(x^2 - y^2), {x, -16.85, -16.08}, {y, -16.85, x}] ` gives me `NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand e^(x^2-y^2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1},{0,1}}. >>`